# Invalid autowire-marked constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

> I have 2 service classes so in controller class 2 @Autowired
> constructors are there whwn i run this got below exception:
>
> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class
> [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Invalid
> autowire-marked constructor: public**
> com.spring.controller.HomeController(com.spring.service.ProductService).
> Found another constructor with 'required' Autowired annotation: public
> com.spring.controller.HomeController(com.spring.service.CustomerService)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:242)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1013)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
> at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

> Controller Class

```
 public class HomeController {
    
    private final CustomerService customerService;
    private final ProductService  productService;
    
     @Autowired
        public HomeController(ProductService productService, CustomerService customerService) {
      this.productService = productService;
      this.customerService = customerService;
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/CustomerDetailsPage"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homepage() 
    {
        
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("CustomerDetailsPage");
        return model; 
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/addCustomerDetails"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addCustomerDetails(CustomerDetails cd) 
    {
        customerService.saveCustomer(cd);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("homepage");
        return model;
    }
```

> Service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomerService  {
    
    private final CdRepo cdRepo;
     
    @Autowired
    public CustomerService(CdRepo cdRepo) {
        
        this.cdRepo = cdRepo;
    }
    public void saveCustomer(CustomerDetails cd) 
    {       
        cdRepo.save(cd);
    }
```

> another service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductService  {

    private final ProductRepo productRepo;
    private final StoredProcedureCall spCall;
    
    @Autowired
    public ProductService(ProductRepo productRepo,StoredProcedureCall spCall) 
    {       
        this.productRepo = productRepo;
        this.spCall = spCall;
    }   
    public void saveProduct(Product product) throws SQLException 
    {
        productRepo.save(product);
        spCall.Procedure();     
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ehrm... You state you have 2 constructors, why? You should have 1 constructor with 2 arguments. If there is just a single constructor you can ommit the `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Lombok, especially @RequiredArgsContructor. If you write your own one, you need to have one constructor annotated with @Autowired and 2 parameters:

```
    @Autowired
    public HomeController(ProductService productService, CustomerService customerService) {
  this.productService = productService;
  this.customerService = customerService;
}
```

Comment: P.S. Mark your injected services as final if you use constructor injection

Comment: Thankyou @SurPrise 2  now i got 3 errors 1.org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' 2.org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productService' defined in file 3.expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: You have to make same for ProductService and make sure ProductRepo is annotated with @Repository

Comment: Sure @SurPrise 2 above i updated the code pls check ones and i ensured both repository classes are annotated with Repository annotation

Comment: You don't need `@Autowired` if there is only a single constructor.

Comment: The error cleanly says that spring is not able to create productService because one of its dependent beans are not in applicationContext. And i guess its because of StoredProcedureCall

Comment: @M.Deinum ty for your comment, actually after working a lot with lombok i forgot such basic things:)

Comment: @SurPrise ur right the problem because of StroedProcedureCall after removing it it works fine